# mysql join three queries into one

Tags: php, mysql

I am calculating purchase, return, sales seperately from a single table for this i have query as follows.

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT sum(quantity) as quantity_in, sum(total) as total_in FROM silk WHERE full_name = '$full_name' AND (type='purchase') AND sale_date BETWEEN '$from_date' and '$to_date'"); $stmt->execute();
$products_in = $stmt->fetchAll();
foreach($products_in as $product_in){
                        $purchase = $product_in['quantity_in'];
                    }

                    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT sum(quantity) as quantity_in, sum(total) as total_in FROM silk WHERE full_name = '$full_name' AND (type='return purchase') AND sale_date BETWEEN '$from_date' and '$to_date'"); $stmt->execute();
                    $products_in = $stmt->fetchAll();
                    foreach($products_in as $product_in){
                        $return_purchase = $product_in['quantity_in'];
                    }

                    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT sum(quantity) as quantity_in, sum(total) as total_in FROM silk WHERE full_name = '$full_name' AND (type='initial_stock') AND sale_date BETWEEN '$from_date' and '$to_date'"); $stmt->execute();
                    $products_in = $stmt->fetchAll();
                    foreach($products_in as $product_in){
                        $initial_stock = $product_in['quantity_in'];
                    }
```

The above takes a very long time, if there were 2000 products it takes neraly 5 minutes to calculate, is there any way to combine the above three queries into one, so that it can run FASTER.
maybe like this,

```
(SELECT sum(quantity) as quantity_in, sum(total) as total_in FROM silk WHERE full_name = '$full_name' AND (type='initial_stock'))
as opening, 
(SELECT sum(quantity) as quantity_in, sum(total) as total_in FROM silk WHERE full_name = '$full_name' AND (type='purchase')) as purchase
WHERE
sale_date BETWEEN '$from_date' and '$to_date'
```

Note: im not good at MySQL, I've only run simple queries through PHP until now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use an group by statement where you can query everything in one query.

```
SELECT type, sum(quantity) as quantity_in, sum(total) as total_in 
FROM silk 
WHERE full_name = '$full_name' AND sale_date BETWEEN '$from_date' and '$to_date'
group by type
```

And in that case it would give you this in your PHP Code

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT type, sum(quantity) as quantity_in, sum(total) as total_in FROM silk WHERE full_name = '$full_name' AND sale_date BETWEEN '$from_date' and '$to_date' group by type"); $stmt->execute();
$products_in = $stmt->fetchAll();
foreach($products_in as $product_in){
    switch ($product_in['type']) {
        case 'purchase':
            $purchase = $product_in['quantity_in'];
        break;
        case 'return purchase':
            $return_purchase = $product_in['quantity_in']
        break;
        case 'initial_stock':
            $initial_stock = $product_in['quantity_in'];
        break;
        // and so on...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not using a `GROUP BY` clause?

```
SELECT type, SUM(quantity) AS quantity_in, SUM(total) AS total_in
FROM silk
WHERE full_name = '$full_name'
AND type IN ('purchase', 'return purchase', 'initial_stock')
AND sale_date BETWEEN '$from_date' and '$to_date'
GROUP BY type
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT type, sum(quantity) as quantity_in, sum(total) as total_in FROM silk WHERE full_name = '$full_name' AND (type='return purchase') AND sale_date BETWEEN '$from_date' and '$to_date' GROUP BY type"); 
$stmt->execute();
$products_in = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Comment: Wouldn't you miss the other types (aka. 'purchase' and 'initial_stock')?

Comment: @MathieuRodic No this would pull the types in the database.

Comment: No because you have a where statement that states that type needs to equal return purchase.

Comment: Yes. But `V Arun Kumar` wanted to return the results for 'purchase', 'return purchase' and 'initial_stock' in one query.

Comment: Yes, and therefor the query that Talifhani wrote will not do the trick because of the WHERE statement that limits the query to only return purchases. so @Mathieu we are on the same page.